# How to convert list of Integer to list of model using dozer

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dozer

Suppose we have the following list:

```
[1,2,3]
```

And the class:

```
public class A {
   private int id;
   // getter and setter ....
}
```

I want to have a list of class `A` with id's corresponding to above list of integers. How would that possible with dozer?

Answer (score 0):

solution using  `List<>`

Your converter :

```
public class MyIntegerToEntityConverter extends DozerConverter<Integer, MyEntity> {
    // TODO constructor + impl
}
```

Your mapping :

```
mapping(MyEntityA.class, MyEntityB.class)
.fields("myIntegerList", "myEntityList",
    hintA(Integer.class),
    hintB(MyEntity.class));

mapping(Integer.class, MyEntity.class)
.fields(this_(), this_(), customConverter(MyIntegerToEntityConverter .class));
```

Where in `MyEntity` will be `Class A` as per your requirement